# CSS Grid row resizing when window resizes

Tags: html, css, grid

I have developed a simple responsive site just for the exercise of doing so.

The site can be accessed here: https://evilernie44.github.io/tofugall/

The problem I have encounter appears to be in relation to css grid rows increasing in size automatically when the width of the window is reduced. So although the site looks ok on Mobile and Desktop it looks pretty awful on a tablet.

Could anyone suggest a good way to fix this or at least a way to avoid this behavior in the future?

I hope this is specific enough as I'm not sure where to start with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

website is looking nice but try to implement the css properly, because on resize of window the css property changes as defined eg margin:10% will be diffrent on mobile, on tab and on pc screen.

If using bootstrap, try to use row and col classes wisely.

Comment: I am only using the jquery framework I think and you are right though, I noticed that the % for margins is creating some problems. Would you suggest fixed margins across multiple break points?